# Как определить стиль с анимацией поворота кнопки?

Tags: xaml

Как определить реюзабельный ресурс с анимацией поворота кнопки? 
пробовал определить стиль с анимацией:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Angle)"
                               To="45" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

и обьявить кнопку

```
     <Button RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="Transform"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
```

но,получаю ошибку `свойство TargetName не может быть задано для типа Style Setter.` Делать свой `ControlTemplate` с преферансом и поэтессами слишком запарно ,ибо надо переопределять полностью все состояния кнопки(нажата/не нажата,активна/неактивна). Делать каждой кнопке свой триггер тоже не выход потому что таких кнопок может быть 
 over 9000.